# How to disable python history saving?

Tags: python-3.x

I am on linux (OpenSuse) machine using CPython with

```
22;~/.../XO/> python3 --version
Python 3.6.10
```

I would like to setup saving/loading python interactive shell history separately for each working directory in which a session has been started. 
I am trying to do it in `/etc/pythonstart` having `export PYTHONSTARTUP=/etc/pythonstart`

The relevant content of my `/etc/pythonstart` is

```
import os
import readline
import atexit

historyFile = ".pyhistory"
cwd         = os.getcwd()

historyPath = cwd + "/" + historyFile

def save_history():
    try:
        readline.write_history_file(historyPath)
    except:
        pass

# read history
if os.path.exists(historyPath):
    readline.set_history_length(100)
    readline.read_history_file(historyPath)

# save history
atexit.register(save_history)
```

It almost works, except python also saves and reads history in `~/.python_history` and it gets merged for all sessions. Is there a way to disable the later behaviour and if yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This modification to the startup file does the job. It does not disable writing to `~/.python_history` but ignores its content on startup.

```
import atexit
import os
import readline

historyFile = ".pyhistory"
startFile   = ".pystart"
cwd         = os.getcwd()

historyPath = cwd + "/" + historyFile
startPath   = cwd + "/" + startFile

def save_history(historyPath=historyPath):
    import readline
    try:
        readline.write_history_file(historyPath)
        readline.clear_history()
    except:
        pass

# ignore history loaded from the standard file
readline.clear_history()

# load history from the custom file
if os.path.exists(historyPath):
    readline.set_history_length(100)
    readline.read_history_file(historyPath)

# register handler
atexit.register(save_history)
```

Answer (score 6):

I have the below in my zshrc:

```
export PYTHONSTARTUP=~/.config/python/pythonrc
```

And in the `pythonrc` file:

```
import readline
readline.write_history_file = lambda *args: None
```

It directly suppresses writing the history file instead of disabling history entirely.  [Source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/297834/414173)

(I'm using python 3.8.5)

Comment: Thanks, but disabling history entirely is not the aim. I want to have history saved for each cwd separately. Disabling can be done with `readline.set_history_length(0)`. The hack in my own answer works, though it is too hacky.

Comment: Note that this will make readline imported in every Python file that is run. It does stop the history file from being written.

Comment: For those who do not need python history, this is the best solution.  The startup script is run only in interactive mode.  It is *not* run for "every Python file".